# Какие существуют способы смены компонентов внутри контейнера на React?

Tags: reactjs, веб-программирование, react-router-dom

Нужно реализовать следующее поведение на React:
При нажатии на одну из ссылок\кнопок (выделено красным) должны сменяться текст, заголовок и картинка (выделены зеленым). Собственно всё, что выделено зеленым находится в отдельном компоненте (таких компонентов всего три). Как оптимально реализовать подобное поведение. Можно ли сделать это через react-router-dom? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `react-router-dom` работает УРЛ страницы... Если нажатие на кнопку будет менять УРЛ страницы - да, такое можно сделать используя `react-router-dom`. Но это же можно проделать если просто изменить стейт. Нужные компоненты отрисуются согласно стейта...

Comment: @ksa Я понял! Спасибо!